# Microsoft Indexing Service and OLEDB With Paging

Tags: asp.net, sql, filesystems, indexing, oledb

I have an ASP.net 2.0 intranet site that uses the indexing service on a folder and its contents.
OLEDB is used to query the files in this folder by using the same technique as discussed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23299/Microsoft-Indexing-Service-and-OLEDB).
This was written by another developer but i am starting to understand his way of working.

But now the clients are complaining about the long loadtime of the page because all files in the folder are queried at once. They are right about the fact that it's slow so i considered using paging (Like in linq Skip().Take()). I know that in SQL this translates as:

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM 
(
   SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
   FROM MyTable
)
AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow
```

But for some reason this does not work when used with OLEDB.
Which version of SQL does this use or do any of you got a suggestiong on how to implement the paging?

EDIT:
Because the above method is only available when using sql Server 2005 or higher, i am going to try a method prior to 2005. I think OLEDB doesn't support Row_Number() or Over.
Going to try:

```
SELECT ... FROM Table WHERE PK IN 
  (SELECT TOP @PageSize PK FROM Table WHERE PK NOT IN
    (SELECT TOP @StartRow PK FROM Table ORDER BY SortColumn)
   ORDER BY SortColumn)
ORDER BY SortColumn
```

Comment: *But for some reason this does not work when used with OLEDB* Does not work how?

Comment: I get an error on executing when i am trying to fill a dataset.
It says that i am missing TABLE in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like MSIDXS doesn't support much SQL functions.
Only the basics like "Select", "Where", "Order by" works. The other functions like "Top", "Rowcount", "Over" don't work. It even fails on "Count(*)".

I implemented paging by using the DataAdapter.Fill() method with 2 integers; startrecord and maxrecord. This is not ideal but the best in this case solution.
Now all records will be collected but only those i need will be stored in the dataset which then is converted to a collection of my own class.

This works fast for the first pages because only the first rows will be looped and returned. But when you have 20 pages the last page will take longer because all the records before it will be looped.

I tested this with a page size of 20 and 400 results.
The first page took 200ms while the last page took around 1,6 seconds.
A noticeable lag but now it only takes place on the last pages and not on the first 10.
There is a search and sorting mechanism so the last pages won't be visited that much.